# Pyspark: add incremental counter to rows, for each different value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add a "row number" to a dataframe, but this "row number" must restart for each new value in a column.

Let me show you an example:

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('2018-01-01', 'John', 0),
    ('2018-01-01', 'Paul', 1),
    ('2018-01-08', 'Paul', 3),
    ('2018-01-08', 'Pete', 4),
    ('2018-01-08', 'John', 3),
    ('2018-01-15', 'Mary', 6),
    ('2018-01-15', 'Pete', 6),
    ('2018-01-15', 'John', 6),
    ('2018-01-15', 'Paul', 6),
], ['str_date', 'name', 'value'])

# Convert str_date to date:
df = df.withColumn('date', to_date(df['str_date'])) \
    .select(['date', 'name', 'value'])

# Sort by name and date
df.orderBy(['name', 'date']).show()

## +----------+----+-----+
## |      date|name|value|
## +----------+----+-----+
## |2018-01-01|John|    0|
## |2018-01-08|John|    3|
## |2018-01-15|John|    6|
## |2018-01-15|Mary|    6|
## |2018-01-01|Paul|    1|
## |2018-01-08|Paul|    3|
## |2018-01-15|Paul|    6|
## |2018-01-08|Pete|    4|
## |2018-01-15|Pete|    6|
## +----------+----+-----+
```

So, what I need is to add a new column with the number of the row for each `name`:

```python
# Expected result
## +----------+----+-----+------+
## |      date|name|value|rowNum|
## +----------+----+-----+------+
## |2018-01-01|John|    0|     1| <- First row for 'John'
## |2018-01-08|John|    3|     2|
## |2018-01-15|John|    6|     3|
## |2018-01-15|Mary|    6|     1| <- First row for 'Mary'
## |2018-01-01|Paul|    1|     1| <- First row for 'Paul'
## |2018-01-08|Paul|    3|     2|
## |2018-01-15|Paul|    6|     3|
## |2018-01-08|Pete|    4|     1| <- First row for 'Pete'
## |2018-01-15|Pete|    6|     2|
## +----------+----+-----+------+
```

I've been trying with the `Window` function, but I'm stuck. Can you please help me?

**Notes:**

- It is guaranteed that the rows will be sorted (and, if they are not sorted, they will be sorted as part of the work pipeline)
- I'm using Spark 2.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ranking function like `row_number` to do this. If there can be ties for a name on a given date, use `dense_rank` instead.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window 
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
#Window definition
w = Window.partitionBy(df.name).orderBy(df.date)
res = df.withColumn('rnum',f.row_number().over(w))
res.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been banging my head all morning with this. I ended putting all together: `df = df.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('date')))`

Answer (score 0):

Vamsi's answer is correct. missed a () for row_number so ...

```
    w = Window.partitionBy(df.name).orderBy(df.date)
    res = df.withColumn('rnum',f.row_number().over(w))  # change after row_number
    res.show()
```